# How to add suffix of serial number for a column in DataFlow ADF

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I have to add a new column which is a combination of existing columns of the source file but this new derived column should have a suffix of 001,002,003...so on in as per the row count of source file.

Suppose I have 5 columns in source file:
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5
The new column C6 should be like this:

C2+C3+C4+001--row 1
,C2+C3+C4+002--row 2
,C2+C3+C4+003--row 3...
C2+C3+C4+00N--row N

where N=total number of rows present in source file.

I thought to use ROWNUMBER() in concat but it did not work.
Can someone help me to understand that how this requirement can be achieved?
Also I do not have any Primary key in my table so C6 is a Composite Primary key I am trying to create for this data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have up to 10 digit number you can use

```
C2+C3+C4+replace(str(row_number() over (order by myorderColumn), 10), ' ', '0')
```

this would make

```
c2c3c40000000001
c2c3c40000000002
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in ADF dataflow follow the below approach.

This is my sample data:

[image]

First, add a **`surrogateKey`** transformation to this like below.

[image]

This will add an incrementing row column like below.

[image]

Now, generate the suffix column using the derived column transformation with below expression.

```
concat(C1,C2,C3,right('000'+toString(key),3))
```

[image]

**Result column:**

[image]

If you have more rows and want the result like 0001,0002 etc.., then change the number and zeros in the expression as per your requirement.

You can delete the `key` column from above using the select transformation later.

Comment: I tried this approach in derived column but if my source file records count is 1lakh then in output total rows it is coming as 3lakhs. I am not sure why it is increasing the number of records.

Comment: **AFAIK**, this approach won't change the number of rows. it is just adding one new column to the source. Try with small sample of data and recheck from your end.